# Using Rselenium and Phantomjs to access Google Trends but having issues with Quota Limits

Tags: r, web-scraping, phantomjs, rselenium, google-trends

I am trying to access the data off of Google Trends. I am using `Rselenium` to access my Gmail account; hoping the credentials will increase my quota in terms of daily limits. Unfortunately, after a few scrapes, I receive an error `page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable` and was curious on how I can avoid this. I am assuming it has to do with me reaching my daily limits. I also used `rvest` and no luck there either. I read a couple of blog posts stating that I have to enable my cookies but I do not know how to do so using Phantomjs.

```
url <- 'https://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=next,geo=US&cid=TOP_QUERIES_0_0'
remDr$navigate(url)
abc <- webElemen02$getPageSource()
top_searches <- read_html(unlist(abc))%>% 
html_nodes(xpath='//*[@class="trends-bar-chart-name"]') %>% 
html_text(trim=TRUE)
```

Comment: That error message is incomplete. Also, if it's really about quota limits, nobody can help you, because that is against the terms and conditions.

Comment: I see, sorry about that. There is a quota limit placed by Google in which I wasn't aware of. I realized this when the code works sometimes and then stops working soon after. Thank you for the response!